# How can I terminate this Ruby `while` loop when the user inputs "no"?

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm working on a program that gives the user two random numbers ranging from 0 to 10 for the user to divide, multiply, add, or subtract.

After every question, the user has the opportunity to stop the program by typing `no`.

I am using a `while` loop for this, but I can't get the loop to terminate when the user inputs `no`. How can I get the program to respond correctly to the user input?

```
def math_num
  nums = [num_1 = rand(1..10), num_2 = rand(1..10), operator = ["+", "-", "/", "*"].sample]
  problem = "What is #{num_1} #{operator} #{num_2}?"
  puts problem

  $input = gets.to_i
  $answer = num_1.send(operator, num_2)

  puts $input == $answer ? "You answered #{$input}, and the answer is #{$answer}! You are correct!" : "The answer is #{$answer}, not #{$input}! You are incorrect!"   

  def try_again
    puts "Would you like to do another question?"
    another = gets.chomp.to_s
    while another != "no"
        math_num
    end
  end

  try_again 

end

math_num
```

Comment: instead of the `while` loop, you can swap it for an `if` statement. `if another != "no"`

Comment: @philipyoo this worked too! Upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the way you are doing it you are getting an infinite loop since the value of the `another` variable is not being updated inside the `while` loop.

Try this instead:

```
def math_num
    while true
        nums = [num_1 = rand(1..10), num_2 = rand(1..10), operator = ["+", "-", "/","*"].sample]
        problem = "What is #{num_1} #{operator} #{num_2}?"
        puts problem

        $input = gets.to_i
        $answer = num_1.send(operator, num_2)

        puts $input == $answer ? "You answered #{$input}, and the answer is #{$answer}! You are correct!" : "The answer is #{$answer}, not #{$input}! You are incorrect!"   

        puts "Would you like to do another question?"
        another = gets.chomp.to_s
        if another == "no"
            break
        end
    end
end

math_num
```